# critical performance with NonLinearNavigationService

Tags: windows-phone-7

I found performance problems with my application.
So, I created a simple app that simulates the behavior of my app.

This simple app saves the values ​​in the xml file (in isolated storage), displays them in a grid, and can erase them. 
The application works fine, but if I add the project NonLinearNavigationService
in some cases the application has serious performance(stability) problems.

You can easily see the problem in this video, that I made:
http://goview.com/?id=9a9ad5d0-a3f2-4f31-ac9f-0879d0ce150b

the code of the app can be downloaded from here:
http://www.fileserve.com/file/ETRb7JP/PhoneApp1.rar

Just try the following steps (as in the video):
1) launch the app and save at least 15-20 values
2) show the grid
3) click on a link to delete a value
4) press the back button

repeat steps 3 to 4

please help me

Comment: anyone can advise me?
I can not continue the development of the app

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in large memory consumption when you generated controls in code-behind for showing the grid. I change logic to listbox and databinding and achieved significantly increasing of performance as you can see on the image.

You could download new project below:

http://www.fileserve.com/file/PK7xQFJ/PhoneApp1.zip

[image: Performance comparison]